# How to allow notifications on headless chrome using selenium webdriver -java

Tags: java, selenium, headless-browser

I am trying to run UI automation tests with seleinum chromedriver. My tests work until I switch to headless,it will not allow notifications.

```
Code snippet:


if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome_headless")) { 
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "lib/chromedriver.exe");
                // Create object of HashMap Class
                Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();

            // Set the notification setting it will override the default setting.

                //Pass the argument 1 to allow and 2 to block and 0 for default
                prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 1);

                // Create object of ChromeOption class
                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                
                options.addArguments("headless");
                options.addArguments("window-size=1366,768");
                // Set the experimental option
                options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);

                // Open chrome browser
                driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
                driver.manage().window().maximize();
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                
            }
```

Comment: Might not be supported in headless mode at the moment by Chrome - Puppeteer has similar issue - https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/3432

Comment: what kind of notification are they ? at least show us the pic?